# Invalid CFStringRef issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having an issue with this message.  It doesn't seem to be able to convert to NSDate with my dateString

```
//dateString = @"2012-03-24 00:00:00 +0000"
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]; //Invalid CFStringRef
    [dateFormatter release];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time zone is specified with an offset `+0000` in

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-03-24 00:00:00 +0000";
```

you have to use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

Notice the double `'Z'` and the removal of `'T'`.

Check [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your date string doesn't have a Z on the end (which the format expects) and it does have a time zone offset (which the format does not expect).

Comment: @TheLearner:  you also have a time zone offset in your dateString