# NSDate and NSDateFormatter return invalid CFStrinfRef

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've one problem with NSDate and NSDateFormatter.

From this NSString

```
NSString *startDate = @"Thu, 19 Apr 2012 13:09:56 +0000";
```

I would obtain a date localized with current locale like this "Thu, 19 Apr 2012 13:09".
I've elaborate this code but the 'endDate' string return nil (within the debugger obtain 'invalid CFStringRef').

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *endDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Where is the bug?

Alex.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it worked like a charm.. So not sure why you get an error?

Comment: Make sure you're getting a valid NSDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the code executed in a non-US locale. I use non-US locales. I have the same `nil` output also.

It seems like we need to `setLocale:` before `setDateFormat:`.

Below code works ok:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

Comment: As mentioned by @R.A, "ZZ" is correct. "ZZZ" means 3 letter timezone code.

Answer (score 0):

Ya its working correctly..Try removing `autorelease` from your `dateFormatter` and then try it again.

And i hope this link is same as yours

[Invalid CFStringRef issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432307/invalid-cfstringref-issue)

Try this answer and change your format option with `"ZZ"` and not `"ZZZ"`.